# detecting and removing watermark using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have question about python image processing,
Are there any method to detecting watermark and also deleting or removing the watermark?

for ex. like this image

http://blackstead.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/SWG-33-1-Hawthorn-Watermark-1024-14.jpg

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

Since the watermark is almost transperant, you can try inpainting technique to remove the watermark. Inpainting technique reconstructs the image by filling any gaps in the image.

Please try the inpainting method in opencv:

```
cv2.inpaint()
```

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html

Comment: Great point. But how will you find the region to be inpainted? It seems quite hard

Comment: @RickM. OK but using Canny edge detection, how can you say that the particular region is 'watermarked'?

Comment: @JeruLuke, if the position of the watermark is constant and same for all images, you can just create a mask at that position

Comment: @v.coder Well in that case it should work. But the question is ... Is the watermark in the same position for all the images??? That is something OP will have to provide

Comment: It depends on the input dataset which you have, if you are planning to remove watermark by one particular company it will always be at same position else it changes

Comment: What if the watermarks can be at any location in the image and the text could be anything too ? How to proceed with that ?